# Is there a way to set System.Windows.Controls.SplashScreen to a System.Windows.Window

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, splash-screen

I was wondering if I can set the splash screen to a programmatic [SplashScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.splashscreen.aspx) instead of having to do it thru an image.

Any ideas?

Best regards

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you are saying. You want to have a Form instead of just a bitmap?

Comment: Yes, but I want it to have the wpf splash screen features as fade etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the splashscreen class in WPF only works with images.

If you want to have something more complete (such a a Window or a UserControl) you should implement your own splash screen logic. It should be easy but you'll probably not be able to show it as fast as the SplashScreen class of the framework.

The framework's splash screen feature uses native code to improve cold startup time.

Comment: Maybe I should do some trick on first startup to render a window to an image?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're really trying to achieve... Could you give us more detail ?

Comment: Maybe, when compiling the application, a helper renders a Window to a png that the splash screen is set to.